# Will banning bots make a site harder to find on search engines?

Tags: web-crawlers, robots.txt

I'm running Apache 2 and a large part of our page views come from bots. Most of those are legitimate ones such as Google and Bing.

I want to parse the logs and get accurate statistics as to how many human visitors I get, so I've temporarily updated *robots.txt* to ban bots on all pages. I know this is only partially effective at preventing bot access, but I'm OK with that.

How will disallowing bots affect users searching for this site? Will it prevent users from finding the page on Google?

Comment: If you want to "parse the logs so I get as few stats from the bots", then do exactly that and _parse_ the logs. (?!)

Comment: Following on what w3d said, all of the major search engine bots will clearly identify themselves with the User-Agent header.

Comment: If you tell Google to go away in robots.txt, they will take your word for it that you don't want to be indexed and your ranking will disappear. Getting your ranking back may take some time after pulling such a stunt.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Banning bots will not let any search engine get the content of the site.

Ultimately you will not rank for any keywords. It would be next to impossible to find your page on Google. You might get referral traffic but no organic traffic.

Note: Robots.txt does not ban bots but ask them not to index  and crawl the site. Which major search engine bot like Google, Yahoo & Bing follow.

Comment: That's what I figured.

Comment: Can you please update your answer to explain that robots.txt does not "ban bots".  It politely asks bots not to crawl the site and for search engines not to index it.  There's absolutely nothing stopping someone from crawling your site anyway.

Comment: To add to what @ErlVolton said. The malicious bots you'd presumably want to ban won't pay any attention to your robots.txt "ban" on bots. So the _only_ affect this ban will have will be to hurt your SEO.

Comment: @ErlVolton +1 for "politely ask bots"

Comment: I think the technical term is "Disallow" which IMO is still not a very good representation of what's happening.  Maybe "RequestNoCrawl" or something would be better :)

Answer (score 21):

Banning bots is a fruitless activity. The only bots that will obey robots.txt are helpful bots like Googlebot and Bingbot. Malicious bots or even less scrupulous search services' bots will ignore your robots.txt.

Banning bots is only a sure way to lose all page ranking with the major search providers AND your logs will still be full of bot traffic.

Comment: +1 _and your logs will still be full of bot traffic._ Only specific denial in .htaccess will keep them out and you still get a 403 for every link they know about from external reference, they just can't suck in a page and start crawling. The list gets mightily long...

Comment: +1 *this* is the answer. There is no stopping bots, **especially** malicious bots.

Comment: @Qix I have seen a few websites that issued an IP ban against anyone that visited a particular URL (that was both forbidden in robots.txt and clearly labeled with "don't click this link or you will get banned" for humans) - that strikes me as a fairly effective way to target unscrupulous crawlers.  Granted, it doesn't do much against a bot specifically designed to target your site.

Comment: @Brilliand that can be very effective for banning clients that attempt to access phpmyadmin, mysql, cgi-bin, .php (when the site is ASP.NET or ROR etc), and other resources that have nothing to do with your site. The common scanning targets.

Comment: @Brilliand And ***terrible*** UX.

Comment: @Qix terrible UX for who? The bots? People don't read robots.txt files commonly.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic `and clearly labeled with "don't click this link or you will get banned" for humans`

Comment: @Brilliand Sound like a fun way to ban other users via CSRF.

Answer (score 3):

Google may still crawl pages ignored by robots.txt and may even list them see [Block URLs with robots.txt](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=en) and [Does Google ignore robots.txt](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/54879/does-google-ignore-robots-txt)

Comment: "Google may still crawl pages _ignored_ by robots.txt" - By "ignored", do you means URLs that aren't blocked by robots.txt?

Comment: That sentence in the "Does Google ignore robots.txt" answer is also **wrong**.   Google may index pages linked by *robots.txt* even when they are disallowed in robots.txt, but it won't crawl them.

Answer (score 3):

It is likely to make your site very difficult or impossible to find in search engines, as the search engines won't send their robots to see what's on your site. They won't know what words you use so it will be hard for them to tell what searches your site might be relevant to.

However it is possible your site will still be displayed in search results, particularly if a high-ranking site has a link to your site. Google and possibly other engines may use information from the link alone to decide to show your site in their results pages.

Comment: This is perfect information. This page is actually a subdomain of our main page which is where I prefer the search engine rank comes from. So knowing that our main page will get the page rankings is perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The data from server logs is limited, and will unavoidably have a high noise to signal ratio, thanks to factors such as bots, caching, CDN.
Analyzing page views is a task for page-tag based analytics.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is to not mess with robots.txt and instead parse your logs, looking at the User-Agent header as mentioned in the comments.  Google, Yahoo, etc. should identify themselves as bots using this header, and disallowing bots via robots.txt would be like driving a truck through your search engine ranking.  As @adria said, there are tools out there that can do this for you.  A very popular one is [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/), here's how they [handle crawler traffic](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1315708?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

Since your stated intention is to

> get accurate statistics as to how many human visitors I get,

The approriate solution is to use a service like [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com.au/analytics/), or [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/), once signed up you insert a snippet of javascript into your page (many engines such as wordpress can do this automatically or with a plugin) which sends information to the monitoring service. Once set up such a service will give a wealth of information about your visitors. Google Analytics is quite amazing in the detail with which it tracks user interactions with your site.

These services are implemented in such a way as to only track real humans and it would be folly to try and re-implement what they already do so well, and they are so useful it's almost folly to *not* use such a service.